# The nativescript-localize do not translate or localize

Tags: nativescript-angular

1. I've create a new app using the template below command:

`tns create my-blank-ng --template tns-template-blank-ng`

2. I've installed the plugin doing

go to app folder:

```
cd my-blank-ng
```

open the vs code editor:

```
code .
```

inside the vs code open a terminal and execute the command below to instal the nativescript-localize plugin (https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-localize#how-to-set-the-default-language)

```
tns plugin add nativescript-localize
```

following the instructions from here https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-localize#how-to-set-the-default-language I've created a new folder i18n inside the folder app (src/app/i18n) and corresponding language files en.json and fr.default.js as described on the guide having the content:

**en.json**

```
{
  "app.name": "My app EN",
  "hello.world": "Hello world ! Hello world TRANSLATED!"
}
```

**fr.default.json**

```
{
  "app.name": "My app FR",
    "hello": {
      "world": "Bonjour le monde ! Hello world !"
    }
}
```

also, the **home.module.ts** looks like:

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeScriptLocalizeModule } from "nativescript-localize/angular";
import { NativeScriptCommonModule } from "nativescript-angular/common";

import { HomeRoutingModule } from "./home-routing.module";
import { HomeComponent } from "./home.component";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        NativeScriptCommonModule,
        HomeRoutingModule,
        NativeScriptLocalizeModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        HomeComponent
    ],
    schemas: [
        NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
    ]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

import { localize } from "nativescript-localize";

@Component({
    selector: "Home",
    templateUrl: "./home.component.html"
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() {
        // Use the component constructor to inject providers.
console.log(localize("Hello world !"));

    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        // Init your component properties here.
    }
}
```

**home.component.html**

```
<ActionBar title="{{ 'app.name' | L }}"></ActionBar>


<StackLayout>
    <!-- Add your page content here -->
    <Label text="{{ 'Hello world !' | L }}" ></Label>
    <Label text="{{ 'I am %s' | L:'user name' }}" ></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

additionally please get the **package.json**

```
{
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.myblankng",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "6.3.1"
    },
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "6.3.0"
    }
  },
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.0",
    "@nativescript/theme": "~2.2.1",
    "nativescript-angular": "~8.20.3",
    "nativescript-localize": "^4.2.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "~6.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "~8.2.0",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "~1.4.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  },
  "gitHead": "fa98f785df3fba482e5e2a0c76f4be1fa6dc7a14",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application"
}
```

BUT THE RESULT IS **disappointing** : NO translation :( 
What I'm doing wrong?

It seems the en.json is not funded (the locale of the simulator is en)

please see the image attached as well[image]

Answer (score 0):

add in app.module.js

```
import { NativeScriptLocalizeModule } from "nativescript-localize/angular";
```

....

```
imports: [
    NativeScriptLocalizeModule
],
```

in actionbar

```
<ActionBar class="action-bar">
<Label>
    <Span class="action-bar-title" text="{{ 'app.name' | L }}" >
    </Span>
</Label>
</ActionBar>
```

in stack layout

```
<StackLayout>
    <Label text="{{ 'hello.world' | L }}" ></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to put the i18n Folder one level up.
For example:
src>i18n
it worked for me.